# Android - Adding a calendar event without reminder

Tags: android, calendar

I'm using the following function to add an event to calendar:

```
public String addEventToCalendar(long startDate, long endDate, String recurrenceRule, boolean isAllDay, String title, String description, String location, long calendarID) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
    if (recurrenceRule != null)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, recurrenceRule);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarID);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, isAllDay);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return null; // we don't have the right permissions
    }
    Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    String eventID = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    return eventID;
}
```

It works, but the resulting calendar event, have a 30 minutes reminder! I'm not able to figure out why. Any clue please?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a default reminder is added after you insert your calendar event.

What you could try is to check if there are any reminder associated with your event right after you inserted it. And delete it if so.

```
CalendarContract.Reminders.query(contentResolver, eventId, projection)
```

will give you a list of reminder associated with the eventId

If the Cursor contains any reminder you can delete it with :

```
getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminderId), null, null);
```

docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Reminders.html

Comment: I've already tried that. It seems to delete the reminder, but then I still receive the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 0);
```

> Whether the event has an alarm or not. Column name.
>
> Type: INTEGER (boolean)
>
> public static final String HAS_ALARM = "hasAlarm";